# inconsistent sed output within a bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I have a below code in a bash script.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo $line | sed 's/\\//g'
    line="`echo $line | sed -i 's/\\//g'`"
    echo "curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"  --request POST  --data '$line'  http://localhost:3000/api/login"

done < data.csv
```

When I run the script, the first sed works as expected and removes all the backslashes whereas the second set generates error on the execution.

```
$ ./notify.sh 
{ "data": { "location": "GA", "message": "Name: Tom Test, Contact Number: 8888888888, City: Atlanta" } }
 sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
 curl --header Content-Type: application/json  --request POST  --data '' http://localhost:3000/api/login
```

Below is the data from csv file. This is sent by a vendor and they do not know why these backslashes are getting added to the file when they generate it from the mysql database.

```
{ "data": { "location": "GA"\, "message": "Name: Tom Test\, Contact Number: 8888888888\, City: Atlanta" } }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Works fine when processing just the example line, Maybe something wrong with the line endings,

Comment: `Below is the data from csv file` Csv is comma separated files. This looks like a json. Looks like only commas are escaped, which probably some tools that converts this json to csv does, so that it's like one field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use ` backticks. Use `$(..)` instead.

The `\\` is replaced by `\` inside `backticks`. So you are executing `s/\//`. Because `/` is escaped `\/` there is one `/` missing and `sed` errors.

Do not use ` backticks. It's behavior is confusing. Use `$(...)` instead.

```
line="$(echo $line | sed -i 's/\\//g')"
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for your help. Sincerely appreciate it.